EPPlus' already has a dependency defined for 'EPPlus.Interfaces
How to resolve this error EPPlus' already has a dependency defined for 'EPPlus.Interfaces
i have added dll for EPPLUS ONLY BUT GETTING THIS ERROR. HAVE TRIED TO UPDATE ALL LATEST VERSION PACKAGES VIA VISUAL STUDIO BUT GETTING SAME ERROR ALL THE TIME HOW TO OVERCOME FROM THIS.
